# Is there a way to set headers for GET requests in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to make get requested with `.Q.hg (HTTP get)`, but I need to edit the request headers to provide API keys. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this function I wrote a few years back for a POC (similar reason - I needed to supply multiple headers). It's based on `.Q.hmb` which underpins `.Q.hp/hg`. Please note - it was never extensively tested & there are likely better alternatives out there, but it will perhaps work as a quick solution.

```
k)req:{[url;method;hd;bd]d:s,s:"\r\n";url:$[10=@url;url;1_$url];p:{$[#y;y;x]}/getenv`$_:\("HTTP";"NO"),\:"_PROXY";u:.Q.hap@url;t:~(~#*p)||/(*":"\:u 2)like/:{(("."=*x)#"*"),x}'","\:p 1;a:$[t;p:.Q.hap@*p;u]1;(4+*r ss d)_r:(`$":",,/($[t;p;u]0 2))($method)," ",$[t;url;u 3]," HTTP/1.1",s,(s/:("Connection: close";"Host: ",u 2),((0<#a)#,$[t;"Proxy-";""],"Authorization: Basic ",.Q.btoa a),($[#hd;(!hd),'": ",/:. hd;()])),($[#bd;(s,"Content-length: ",$#bd),d,bd;d])}
```

It takes 4 arguments:

1. Resource URL
2. HTTP method
3. Dictionary of headers
4. Message body as JSON object

Sending a request to a test server..

```
q).j.k req["https://httpbin.org/get";`GET;("Content-Type";"someOtherHeader")!(.h.ty`json;"blah");""] // no body so pass empty string
args   | (`symbol$())!()
headers| `Content-Type`Host`Someotherheader`X-Amzn-Trace-Id!("application/jso..
url    | "https://httpbin.org/get"
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! (again!).

Comment: One extra question- how can I embed K in a Q script? I've tried putting `\` around it (as I would toggle in the console), but it doesn't seem to like it when it's in a Q file. The function works brilliantly by the way.

Comment: Prefix the statement with k) as I've done above